# Cannot highlight text in Internet Explorer (IE)

Tags: html, wordpress, internet-explorer

On my website http://www.ruigrok-nederland.nl/  i cant select text.
Its working fine on Chrome and Firefox.

How is this possible?
I am 100% sure it is not a configuration in Internet explorer, because it works well on other pages.

Thanks

Comment: Give us the code of your page by using jsfiddle

Comment: Wich code? Becouse its on all pages.

Comment: please be more specific.  I assume that you are talking about trying to select text via JavaScript?  please edit your question and provide an example of your HTML and all JS code that you are trying to use... how and when which of it works, and on which browser.  Try to include any errors or warnings in the developer/debug console for each browser

Comment: @KEVIN start with ALL your code if you don't know what is going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your page I am getting an error every time I click the left mouse button or moving the cursor. The onclick error is stopping IE from dealing with what is happening when you and click-drag to select the text.

It is possible to select the text using keyboard shortcuts. If you fix the JavaScript errors that I mentioned above the page will start to work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

your error exists here:

> function mousePos (e) {
>       if (!mie) {
>           mouseX = e.pageX; 
>           mouseY = e.pageY;
>       }
>       else {
>           mouseX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
>           mouseY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
>       }
>
> ```
> document.show.mouseXField.value = mouseX;
> ```

There is no `document.show` object.  I don't know where you're getting this from/what sample could you got it from???  Also, you are mixing variables... your function is getting `e` as the parameter/variable event object, but you are using `event` in your else statement.  That won't work since `event` is undefined.

> ```
> document.show.mouseYField.value = mouseY;
> ```

If you don't have a good reason otherwise, you can use jQuery to do this, since one of the goals and benefits of jQuery is cross-browser functionality:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>select demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    color: blue;
  }
  div {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Click and drag the mouse to select text in the inputs.</p>
  <input type="text" value="Some text">
  <input type="text" value="to test on">
  <div></div>

<script>
$( ":input" ).select(function() {
  $( "div" ).text( "Something was selected" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```